# How to close Selenium WebDriver from Windows CMD when using iRetryAnalyzer?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, command, testng

I am working on an automation script that continuously loads an internal webpage my company is developing in order to measure performance. I run this script every night and have been using Eclipse. I would click run on the Eclipse IDE at night and press End every morning. I have recently integrated Ant so that I can run everything from command line. The problem is, because I am using an iRetryAnalyzer in my testNG xml  file, every time a window closes, another will open and the test will repeat x times. This was not an issue because when "ending" via Eclipse, all processes are terminated (the retry class does not fire).

However, when running the script through CMD, there are issues. When I "close" the CMD window, my script will still run in the background. When I use:

```
taskkill /F /IM / chromedriver.exe /T
```

The chrome browser running the tests will close, but my Retry listener class will fire and another browser will open up, and the tests begin again. I am looking for a solution to completely end the script, including any retries, similar to how "ending" the run in Eclipse IDE works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried looking for all the processes that are running to see if there’s anything else you can kill?

Comment: Can you please show some code snippets around the relevant areas that you are mentioning? That way we can get an idea of what your Retry Listener looks like, what your test looks like.